# Current, when Zener and normal diode in parallel? (picture inside)

Tags: current, diodes

1.) What are the currents , I1 and I2? And why?

[image]

2.)

What are the currents here (when the diodes are the same):

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We're not here to do your homework for you. Show your attempt first.

Comment: Happy to help but without some effort on your part you will never learn.

Comment: It is so obviously a home work problem. It is also extremely disappointing that some folks take it upon themselves to answer questions like this.

Comment: @derstrom8 It's not a homework question I just inventing problems on my own. So if something have a lower voltage drop ,that will get the full current, right?

Comment: Please tell why the first answer is downwoted? Is it the answer whats wrong , or he just answered to a "seemingly homework question" and thats why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework without any attempt at a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I1 = 0 mA, I2 = 10 mA. The diode have lower voltage drop (0.7 V) than the zener (5.6 V).
2. Hard to say, I1 = 0-10 mA and I2 = 10 mA - I1. They may share but probably not and I1 will be either 0 or 10 mA after a short while. Silicon diodes have negative temperature coeficient so once one of them starts to take more current, it will heat up, have lower voltage drop, take more current and so on until saturated.

Comment: In the original question (2) it says that the diodes are the same.

Comment: @MichaelKaras. Doesn't matter. Any difference between them will have positive feedback and sooner or later one of them will take all the current. If they are thermally coupled hard to each other, you can reach an equilibrium between them.

Comment: So if one of the diodes have lower voltage drop that one will take the full current eventually?

Comment: @Filkor. Exactly so for 99.99 % of all silicon diodes (there may be heavily doped exteme examples which may differ, but nothing you will run in to). Schottky (garmanium) is the oposite, hence they are heavily used in paralell since current sharing is guaranteed per design.

Comment: @winny Thanks winny. I dont know why this is downvoted though..

Comment: @Filkor. You are welcome! Many here only like to hear that people should read the manual, you should not do anything with electricity unless you are a trained electrician and don't check the laws of physics, only read the datasheet. *rant mode off*

Comment: @Filkor it is down voted because you made no attempt on trying to solve your own question. More importantly, this site hates doing other people's homework. This site is for unique and inspiring questions, not the repetitive questions given by teachers.

Comment: All I care about is that the worlds average knowledge just became slightly higher now that OP has a deeper understanding of semiconductors. :-)

Comment: You appear to have confused "got someone else to answer his/her homework question so as to not think or learn" with "deeper understanding" - lying about it being a homework problem is not surprising, but insufficient to make an obvious homework problem not be one.

Comment: Yes, that's one risk but I did take "So if one of the diodes have lower voltage drop that one will take the full current eventually?" as this guy got what this is about. :-)